# Permanent Redirect Legacy Routes for static files in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Our old ASP.net site stored static images in a sub directory on the root called **/images**.

Our new ASP.net MVC site stores these images in the new layout of **/Content/Images**

I've changed all the pages in the site to cope with the new folder structure, but I'd like to set up Permanent Redirects from the old static images to the new location.

Our site is hosted, and I don't have control over IIS, so what is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: It turns out that my web host did let me have control over IIS, and therefore I was able to use the Url Rewriting module to accomplish my requirements. However, I will leave this question up in case the community provide an answer for those who are in the situation I thought I was in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following code for my MVC 2 websites:

```
// The legacy route class that exposes a RedirectActionName
public class LegacyRoute : Route
{
    public LegacyRoute(string url, string redirectActionName, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler)
    {
        RedirectActionName = redirectActionName;
        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}); // is not actually called
    }

    public string RedirectActionName { get; set; }
}

// The legacy route handler, used for getting the HttpHandler for the request
public class LegacyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("success");
        return new LegacyHandler(requestContext);
    }
}

// The legacy HttpHandler that handles the request
public class LegacyHandler : MvcHandler
{
    public LegacyHandler(RequestContext requestContext) : base(requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("success");
        ProcessRequest(requestContext.HttpContext);
    }

    protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string redirectActionName = ((LegacyRoute) RequestContext.RouteData.Route).RedirectActionName;
        var route = new Route(redirectActionName, ((LegacyRoute)RequestContext.RouteData.Route).Defaults, new MvcRouteHandler());

        // Copy all of the querystring parameters and put them within RouteContext.RouteData.Values
        var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var s in RequestContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            values.Add(s.Key, s.Value);
        }
        foreach (var s in httpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
        {
            values.Add(s, httpContext.Request.QueryString[s]);
        }
        var data = route.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext, new RouteValueDictionary(values));

        httpContext.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Location", "/" + data.VirtualPath + "/");
        httpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Then I simply add legacy routes to my route map:

```
routes.Insert(13, new LegacyRoute("search", "search/{query}", new LegacyRouteHandler()));
```

Comment: +1 How do you use this code? Where do you create the .cs file for the LegacyHandler, MVC3? How will this work to redirect url's as: ~/products.aspx?id=1

Comment: I would add the line `httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;`. I also **had to remove the code to add a slash at the end** because it was breaking my URL params from `?foo=bar` into `?foo=bar/`, and then my Action would throw an error because `bar/` is not a valid value for `foo`.

Comment: there's a blog article with this code (or very similar) explaining usage more thoroughly -  http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/aspnet-mvc---legacy-url-routing.aspx