# How to map resource routes in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

does anyone know how I can redirect all requests to say /images to /Content/images in MVC3? I just want certain naming conventions.

Thanks,

Comment: How are those requests generated? Do you have some legacy site for which you want to change urls?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like to user permanent redirects? Somebody already asked the same question, and the answer is there: [Permanent Redirect Legacy Routes for static files in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4664890/191966)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can give is to not ever try and request any content directly from the view itself.

Rather create HTML helpers to handle these requests and only specify the actual path to the files in these helpers. That way when things inevitably move around you change the path once in your helper and every view just works. this is an example of my image helper, I think I stole this from Rob Conery and his amazing Tekpub MVC Sample.

In this class I declare static variables pubdir (for my content directory) and imageDir (for my images subfolder in my content directory)

```
  public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName, string attributes)
    {
        fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pubDir, imageDir, fileName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes))
        {
            return string.Format("<img src='{0}'/>", helper.AttributeEncode(fileName));
        }
        var temp = string.Format("<img src='{0}' '{1}' />", helper.AttributeEncode(fileName), helper.AttributeEncode(attributes));

        return temp;
    }
```

I overloaded this with another method when all I have is the filename.

```
public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return Image(helper, fileName, "");
    }
```

Now when I want an image in my view I call

```
 @Html.Image("hello.jpg")
```

All I specify is the filename, and the image tag is returned to me. 
You can actually take this further (if you want) and make a method called HelloImage that accepts no arguments, where you specify the filename in the actual method, incase the image is ever renamed..

I've done this for things like banners and logo's that are reused all over. I've started doing the same thing for actionlinks as well, in case controllers, actions and areas get moved or renamed.

http://codingsmith.co.za/extending-the-actionlink-helper-in-mvc/

Comment: What about images linked-to from css files? They match OP's question but not this answer.